# SpriteKit Game Scene Transition Memory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

Xcode 9.4.1, Spritekit, ObjectiveC

I've made an app game using the above. Similar to Flappy Bird i.e
a Main Character on the screen, simple gameplay.

I have 2 scenes: Game Scene & Character selection. Each scene's memory usage is 20mb.

When I play the game, the memory usage shows 20mb. Then when I transition to the character selection screen, it shows 40mb (Game Scene's 20mb + Character Scene's 20mb).

QUESTION is: Is that standard practice? Or should I be removing the Game Scene's 20mb when I transition to the Character Scene?

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes that is normal,  you are transitioning, so you need both scenes available for a transition to work, otherwise it would be black

Comment: Thanks KOD. And when the scene has loaded and I’ve transitioned, should I be removing the previous scene’s 20mb? I’m assuming not. It’s holding onto it for faster loading later isn’t it.

Comment: No it should release automatically when done

Comment: Done a bit of googling etc. Added a deinit method to test deallocation. Oddly, It gets called fine... But I seem to have a 1mb leak. ie memory usage goes up by 1mb every scene change.

Comment: Ok... the very first time any scene is changed in the game, it doesn't run the deinit method. But from then on, it works fine every time. Very peculiar.